# Is there any way to speed up PRAW's comment parsing?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm writing a script to scrape text data (posts and their comments) with praw, and comments add so much time to the download it's ridiculous.

If I only download posts and no comments, it gets ~100 per second, but if I download comments with the posts, it goes down to 1-2 per second, and that's just for top level comments. If I include nested comments, it takes ~5-10 minutes for 1 post (granted the post I tested on was the top post from /r/raskreddit, but still). Here's the method I'm using, please let me know if there's a way to make this any faster!

```
for top_level_comment in submission.comments.list():
    commentnumber += 1
    comment1= long variable, not important
    savepost.write(comment1)
    for comment in top_level_comment.replies:
        parentvar = comment.parent_id
        parent = reddit.comment(parentvar[3:])
        parentauthor = str(parent.author)
        comment2 = again, long variable
        savepost.write(comment2)
```

I've also tried this method, thinking that fewer for statements with comment requests might help, but it didn't

```
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    if str(comment.parent_id[:2]) == "t1":
    parent = reddit.comment(comment.parent_id[3:])
    comment2 = super long variable, not important
    if comment.parent_id not in commentidlist:
        commentidlist.append(comment.parent_id)
        comment1 = Again, long variable
        savepost.write(comment1)
        print("Wrote parent comment Id: "+comment.parent_id[3:])
    savepost.write(comment2)
```

Comment: For every comment batch you fetch with generator (like `submission.comments` or `comment.replies`) your client has to perform reddit api request. Reddit API has restriction of 30 requests per minute. Best you can do in this situation is change fetching logic to minimize amount of requests.

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#section_listings for a description of what API calls are being made to generate listings

Comment: a reason why it may be acting slow is that you are using .write() which I believe is writing to a file. That process is relatively slow. You might be able to speed it up if you were to separate your write to file and gather data parts.